# Right way to set up Rust using Vim

Tags: vim, rust, rust-cargo

I've finally started to dive into [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/) and want to clarify some issues when it comes to setting up everything nicely.

I'm using vim on Linux and found a nice plugin for syntax highlighting. Autocompletion is somewhat troublesome though, using phildawes/racer.

The plugin needs the src location for Rust which is in fact not that big of a deal, if I would know where said directory was (I only found the binaries and libs when using the suggested `curl <...> | sh` install). The sources are downloadable separately, although I didn't find an install for Rust that sets up the sources in let's say e.g. /usr/local/src/rust only the binaries and libs.

Second I've looked through the Cargo docs and and didn't find anything to where the extern dependencies are cloned into (wouldn't this be the source directory?)

Also should the Rust sources be updated setting up everything manually is kind of lame?

Is the quintessence to clone the Rust repository and build it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The plugin needs setting up the src location for rust which is in fact not that big of a deal, if I would know where said directory was

I couldn't find the sources either. If you just want the sources without all the history:

For 1.0.0,

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch 1.0.0 --single-branch https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/
```

or for nightly

```
git clone --depth=1 --single-branch https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/
```

> Second I've looked through the cargo docs and and didn't find anything to where the extern dependencies are cloned into (wouldn't this be the source directory?)

In the standard installation, there's a directory `.cargo` in your home directory, which contains `git/checkouts` for the cloned crates.

You should probably try [multirust](https://github.com/brson/multirust) though, which allows you to easily manage multiple Rust installations in `~/.multirust`.

With multirust, your crate checkouts might be in e.g. `~/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/cargo/git/checkouts`, not `~/.cargo/git/checkout`.

> Is the quint essence to clone the rust repository and build it yourself?

No, that's luckily not necessary anymore, unless you're working on the compiler/stdlibs, or trying to cross-compile. With multirust, updating is reduced to `multirust update` or `multirust update nightly`, etc.

Comment: Now that was helpful, did I get it right that `~/.multirust/.../git/checkouts` will then be the correct value for `$RUST_SRC_PATH`?

Comment: @hakononakani: Unfortunately, that's not the case. The correct RUST_SRC_PATH would be wherever you git clone the rust repository. `~/.multirust/toolchains/*/git/checkouts` will contain the code of crates you downloaded, but you can't (yet) rely on auto-completion based on that code. There's [a GitHub issue for that](https://github.com/phildawes/racer/issues/264). racer might automatically look in `~/.cargo` for the code of certain crates, but it doesn't appear to be reliable yet.

Comment: @hakononakani: [It appears](https://github.com/phildawes/racer/blob/3827cf13b2f8be71c27285cd7c017a4701d0c2b7/src/racer/cargo.rs#L57-L80) that racer will also inspect crates downloaded with multirust.